# Cannot get Jquery DateTimePicker to display in mvc4

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, datetimepicker

here is my script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
   // alert("jquery working fine, still no display..");
    $(".datepicker").datetimepicker({
        showAnim: 'slideDown',
        dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yyyy'
    });
});
</script>

 <input type="text" class="datepicker" />
```

The actual Datepicker works great, firebug shows this script, the jqueryUI, the timepicker-addon.js, slider.js, and datepicker.js, jquery is selecting the textboxes.

but alas, still no datetimepicker displaying

I've tried using id's/classes, rearranging the order the scripts are loaded. I would say that the addon is just bunk, but so many seem to have no troubles at all with it.
Does anyone know what I am missing?

Comment: Just for clarification, is the Date picker part of datetimepicker showing up, but not the time picker part? Or does the datepicker plugin work great, but not the datetimepicker plugin?

Comment: I can see how that is ambiguous, when I use $(selector).datepicker it displays correctly, however, if I use $(selector).datetimepicker nothing happens

Comment: In that case I would recommend checking the order in which the javascript files are loaded to make sure the timepicker plugin loads after the datepicker, and also check to make sure you aren't getting any scripting errors either when it tries to set up the timepicker or when it should display it.

Comment: "~/_files/scripts/lib/jquery.ui.datepicker.min.js",
                        "~/_files/scripts/lib/jquery.ui.slider.min.js",
                        "~/_files/scripts/lib/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js"

this is my bundle code, jquery ui is in seperate bundle, but it must be fine due to all the jquery in my project functioning save for the datetimepicker. I may try to redownload from another source

Comment: not trying to be difficult and I appreciate the help

Comment: It may be nothing, but I notice the datepicker and slider files use periods between words, but the timepicker uses dashes. Is that the correct file name? Is the file being correctly included in the bundle?

Comment: That's the way it shows in the Solution Explorer at least, and firebug is picking up that the script is active

Comment: I'm pretty much out of ideas then, other than setting a breakpoint and stepping through line by line to see what's failing, but that can be difficult, especially with minified code.

Comment: true story, but thanks again and I'm gonna go break it real quick

Comment: @Chaz3n most of the example I have seen using the id like this  $("#datepicker").datetimepicker.. please can try this and let me know

Comment: @HatSoft, I had tried this method first. I should have noted this because it is the method I had seen most.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code works perfectly fine for me:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index</title>
    <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" class="datepicker" />

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.21/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('.datepicker').datetimepicker({
            showAnim: 'slideDown',
            dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy'        
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Gives the following result as can be seen in this [live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/DfqCH/):

[image]

So I guess there must be something wrong with your script inclusions and maybe their order. Unfortunately since you haven't shown your code it is difficult to be able to say more.

Comment: inclusions are in comments sorry. I will try to reorder like you have them. Can I use dynamic links in Bundle?

Comment: On a side note, are there any negatives to using double quotes in selector?