# DateTimePicker in MVC 4

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, datetimepicker

I am using this jQuery datetimepicker and use it same like this [Cannot get Jquery DateTimePicker to display in mvc4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11478266/cannot-get-jquery-datetimepicker-to-display-in-mvc4).

But with some corrections, I am using existed scripts in MVC, e.g.

Instead this:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I use this:

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
```

etc. and it works, but image of next and prev is not shown, I can't find a rows for this two buttons. Also, How can I generate seconds in this code...

thanks for help

Comment: you don't have images of it..download and place them as well in the folder

Comment: I have done this, I put it in my Content folder and name it: next.png and prev.png

Comment: you need to check in css what is the path of images change it yo yours or place images where the path is defined in css

Comment: that is what I am searching for, In this css, I can not found it: http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css

Comment: here it is place the images folder in the folder where css file is, here is the path of images from the css link you gave ``url(images/ui-bg_glass_75_ffffff_1x400.png)``

Comment: use firebug to check what url is genrated

Comment: firebug? does it worsks in Chrome...

Comment: you can use chrome inspect element

Comment: does chrome report 404's in the network tab when loading the page?  that will rule out whether you have the image sin the wrong location or whether some styling issues is not showing them

Comment: somehow live demo stops to work :( what ever...

Comment: hmmm, this images are in default inside my app, when I create project Basic MVC app. Also name of images are same as in app, but it somehow doesnt work...